Origin of "wise guy" to mean a member of the Mafia (US)
Grammarist claims without giving any sources:

The term wise guy to mean a smart aleck came into use in the later 1800s in North America. The expression wise guy to mean a member of the Mafia came into use in the 1970s.

Idiomorigins likewise claims:

this usage dates from the 1970s.

How did a term that meant "smart aleck" become a term that meant "a member of the Mafia"?

Green's says it meant "criminal" from the early 20th century, and before that "anyone who thinks they are particularly knowing or clever; a general derog. description: the implication being that the person is too clever for their own good". You could easily guess how that might develop, although it might be hard to find clear evidence.

@StuartF I would suspect that one contributing factor is that "wise guy" would readily be applied to children who have chronic disciplinary problems in school -- or out of it.

It's common for both police and criminals to use euphemisms, it seems likely that it originated from one of those groups. Probably similar to "made man".

In the 1930s and earlier, "wise guy" meant people who were obnoxiously confident. Sometimes, it meant "suckers": underground slang for people who were decidedly not wise, but rather stupid enough to be taken advantage of.
So how did it turn from meaning "an asshole," or "a sucker," to meaning "a gangster?"  The answer is that in the 1940s and early 1950s, a lot of gangsters got pulled over by police who would say "Okay, wise guy (meaning an asshole), you're going to have plenty of time to think about this in the slammer!"  (They always used these exact words.)
Epithets are frequently appropriated by the recipients and incorporated into their own lexicon, which is what happened with the gangsters who began referring to themselves as "wise guys."  The term was popularized in the movie "Goodfellas," and then Hollywood took it all the way to this question here and now I'm answering it.

Here are five definitions from Green's Dictionary of Slang, all very useful. The term has several meanings and has evolved over time:
It first appeared in Artie by George Ade

"Well, I guess yes. I know this town like a book. I can begin at the first card and go through the deck, but out there they lose me. They had me lookin' like a Reub all the time. The worst one was the hired hand. His name was Elias. I see him up here the time of the World's Fair, dodgin' cable cars and lookin' up at the skyscrapers. He was dead lucky to get out o' town without havin' his clothes lifted, and, at that, I ain't sure he did. But down at the farm, he was the wise guy and I was the soft mark.

"Now you 've got me guessin'. I 've talked to twenty wise guys that 've been ridin' and every one of 'em sings a different song. Every guy cracks up his own wheel, and says all the others is made out o' sheet iron and bum castin's. I 've had five or six chances to get inside prices.
Indiana University.edu


1. (US) a shrewd person.
Meaning 2:
Also, the same dictionay and also in 1896:
2. (US) anyone who thinks they are particularly knowing or clever; a general derog. description: the implication being that the person is too clever for their own good.
1896    [US]    F. Hutcheson Barkeep Stories 171:

‘Say, lemme tell you somet’in’, Mr. Wise Guy,’ broke in the barkeep.

3. (US) a criminal.
1909    [US]    H. Green Mr. Jackson 59:

‘Cheer up, my boy, they ain’t no more prisons fur you’ [...] I had to start out an’ be a wise guy again after livin’ with no effort fur mighty near a year.

4 . (US) as a form of personal address.
1940    [US]    W.R. Burnett High Sierra in Four Novels (1984) 323: Look, wise-guy. For fifteen years I’ve been listening to sob-stories.
wise guy re Mafia dates to 1955:
5. (orig. US) a ‘made’ member of an organized crime syndicate, usu. the US Mafia.
1955    [US]    B. Appel Tough Guy [ebook]

The wise boys down the West Side said with a wink that there must be two kinds of parole. ‘One kind the coppers hound you all the time. The other kind’s the Ownie Madden kind with the coppers kissing your ass’.

